# Black background after rendering

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a problem with background transparency. In the viewport the background is transparent but after rendering it is black. I checked transparent in film and also render in RGBA but it's still black. Also add the image to photoshop to check if it is from my photo viewer but it is not.
Does anyone had the same problem?

This is how it looks in viewport:
[image]

This is while rendering:
[image]

And this is the final image:
[image]

I have no idea why it adds a black background

A screenshot from compositing nodes:
[image]

Comment: And you saved it as a PNG or which format?

Comment: So, are you using the compositor? If so, would you mind sharing a screenshot from the node setup there?

Comment: Yes, just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a *Lens Distortion* node in the *Compositor*. This doesn't support alpha transparency and makes the background black. Effects like *Dispersion* work on all pixels to create the color distortions, therefore it needs an opaque image.

Of course you could take the *Alpha* output of the *Render Layers* and plug it into the *Alpha* input on the *Composite* and *Viewer* node. But in this case distortions that are exceeding the opaque area of the original image will be cut off.

A workaround would be to plug the *Alpha* output into another *Lens Distortion* node with the same settings as the first one. This way the  alpha will be distorted in the same way and you can use this on the *Alpha* inputs of *Composite/Viewer* nodes.

Just be aware that semi-transparent areas resulting from this will be mixed with a black background. This might make problems with overlaying the image on backgrounds with brighter colors.

[image]

Since effects like dispersion are dependent on the image colors, overlaying a different background color than black also results in incorrect results:

[image: dispersion transparent vs opaque]

This is of course an extreme dispersion. But as you can see, with transparency you first of all have a less colorful dispersion, since it is semi-transparent. The other things is, with a white background added before the dispersion effect, the color would not be blue, but yellow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know it can effect the transparency. After removing the node it can be export without a background

Comment: @Mona_ I'll edit the answer to give a workaround. You can have transparency with _Lens Distortion_, the problem is just it's mixing with a black background which can be problematic if you want to overlay a bright background withthe transparent image.

Comment: @Mona_ Last edit for today ;) Just another example what the problem with dispersion on transparent background is.

Answer (score 0):

The composite node needs to have "use alpha" enabled.

[image]

You can find this node by going to "compositing" in the top bar and then clicking on "use nodes".

However, this checkbox should be enabled by default, so it might not be the problem.

Comment: If she wouldn't know where the compositing is and didn't enable _Use Nodes_, she would most certainly not have to go there and enable _Use Alpha_, because by default Blender uses the Alpha when set to RGBA and _Film > Transparent_ enabled. Just sayin'

Comment: I know, but there's no other reason I can think of. Besides, I said in my response that "this checkbox should be enable by default, so it might not be the problem".

Comment: Use Alpha is enabled. I will add images in the question what it looks like.

Comment: @ColinT That's why I voted the question for "needs more details / clarification." Because there is no information if the compositor is used, and there are other possible reasons like e.g. saving in JPG instead of PNG. I just wanted to say: if she used the compositor, the explanation how to enable it is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

When you save your .png, enable RGBA[image]

Comment: I quote from the question: _"I checked transparent in film and also render in RGBA"_